# Screen capture video Live streamming

Tags: iphone

I would require to send live video to server and video is captured from the screen Using
this code...

```
videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:[self tempFileURL] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

//Configure video
NSDictionary* videoCompressionProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1024.0*1024.0], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
                                       nil ];

NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.frame.size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.frame.size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               videoCompressionProps, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                               nil];

videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];

NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
NSDictionary* bufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

avAdaptor = [[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:bufferAttributes] retain];

//add input
[videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];
[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1000)];
```

Comment: I have developed Drawing app and want to share screen over server  Like live mirror images